# Prestashop won't work when migrating to a new domain

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I moved Prestashop 1.7.0 to a new web hosting and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Defuse\Crypto\Exception\EnvironmentIsBrokenException' with message
>   'Your system does not have a secure random number generator.' in
>   /membri/gbdns/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Core.php:110 Stack
>   trace: #0 /membri/gbdns/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Key.php(23):
>   Defuse\Crypto\Core::secureRandom(32) #1
>   /membri/gbdns/classes/PhpEncryptionEngine.php(101):
>   Defuse\Crypto\Key::createNewRandomKey() #2
>   /membri/gbdns/classes/PhpEncryption.php(97):
>   PhpEncryptionEngineCore::createNewRandomKey() #3
>   /membri/gbdns/config/bootstrap.php(131):
>   PhpEncryptionCore::createNewRandomKey() #4
>   /membri/gbdns/config/config.inc.php(56):
>   require_once('/membri/gbdns/c...') #5 /membri/gbdns/index.php(27):
>   require('/membri/gbdns/c...') #6 {main} thrown in
>   /membri/gbdns/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Core.php on line 110

I have PHP 5.6 and Mysql perfectly running

I tried disabling the flag `PS_CIPHER_ALGORITHM` maybe I don't have crypt in the new domain, but the problem still persists

Comment: did you install via composer?

Comment: Add `$ex->getMessage()` to the exception's message on line 111 of file `/membri/gbdns/vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Core.php` like this : `......secure random number generator. ' . $ex->getMessage());`. This should show the message of the catched exception. Let's see what kind of infos it brings.

Comment: There is a 'bug' that doesn't allow run with php version <= 7, or maybe appear some strange errors. However I don't recommend to use this version to build a production site. Use the latest 1.6 (1.6.1.9 at the moment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has already been reported to PrestaShop and they have said it will be fixed in 1.7.0.1 with other things.

http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/BOOM-1735

To temporarily fix it you can follow the instructions below:

- You can set the random_compat version to 1.4 and use composer install, but you will need to have ssh access to your server.

OR

- To fix it you can update the /vendor/paragonie/random_compat/ with the last version available here: https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/releases/tag/v2.0.4